# Windows 8.1 freezes while installing WP8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, installation, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am installing WP8 SDK from `*.ISO` image for Visual Studio 2012 and on the final installation step (WP8 Emulator Configuring) after about 20-30 minutes PC just freezes so I cant do anything. Image on the screen remains motionless and all I can do just turn mu PC off by unplugging the power source.

> Here is my PC stats:
>
> - AMD FX-8350 4Ghz 8core
> - Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 Motherboard
> - 8Gb of RAM
> - GTX 460 1Gb

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "issue" when I installed WP8 SDK, but actually it downloads a lot of data, so it can take up hours to finish the installation. I had to wait up to 3hrs to finish it, so don't worry, just be patient.

Here, at this [Link](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk?logged_in=1), the size of the package is up to 1.6GB (English version).

Comment: The matter is that i already am installing it from .ISO (which is 1.6GB) so it already is downloaded... Image on the screen freezes literally so i cant even move cursor.

Comment: Your cursor is not moving in installer's window? Or it is not moving in Windows?

Comment: In windows, so i can't do anything (f.e. switch the programs, open start screen.... or open taskManager...)